# JPanel does not fill containing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Hi so I'm writing an simple physics engine to understand object collisions and Java graphics a bit better, and so far I have successfully written the code to add the JPanel to the JFrame and allow them to show up somewhat the correct size, but when I view the actually program, the JPanel seems tobe the right size but it does not start in the upper corner of the window, but rather the upper left of the frame. I seem to have this problem alot where I want something to be at (0, 0) and starts in the upper corner of the frame rather than the panel. Here is my code:

I have an engine class that extends JFrame and contains the main method -->

```
package io.shparki.PhysicsEngine;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Engine extends JFrame{

    public Engine(){
        super("Physics Engine and Simulator");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new EnginePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();

        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Engine();
    }

}
```

and this is my second class, the EnginePanel which extends JPanel and implements Runnable -->

```
package io.shparki.PhysicsEngine;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class EnginePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    private static final int WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
    private static final int SCALE = 4;
    public int getWidth() { return WIDTH * SCALE; }
    public int getHeight() { return HEIGHT * SCALE; }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){ return new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE); }

    private static final int FPS = 85;
    private static final int PERIOD = 1000 / FPS;

    private int currentFPS = 0;

    private Thread animator;
    private boolean running = false;

    private Graphics dbg;
    private Image dbImage = null;


    public EnginePanel(){
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addNotify(){
        super.addNotify();
        startEngine();
    }
    public void startEngine(){
        running = true;
        animator = new Thread(this, "Animator");
        animator.start();
    }
    public void stopEngine(){
        running = false;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (dbImage != null){
            g.drawImage(dbImage,  0,  0,  null);
        }
    }
    public void paintScreen(){
        Graphics g;
        try{
            g = this.getGraphics();
            if ( g != null && dbImage != null){
                g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
            g.dispose();
        } catch(Exception ex) { System.out.println("Graphics Context Error : " + ex); }
    }
    public void run(){
        running = true;
        init();

        Long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleepTime;
        while(running){
            beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            updateEngine();
            renderEngine();
            paintScreen();

            timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
            sleepTime = PERIOD - timeDiff;
            if (sleepTime <= 0){
                sleepTime = 5L;
            }
            currentFPS = (int) (1000 / (sleepTime + timeDiff));

            try{
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        }

    }




    private TextField FPSTextField;


    public void init(){
        FPSTextField = new TextField("Currnet FPS: " + currentFPS, 25, 25);
    }
    public void updateEngine(){
        FPSTextField.setText("Currnet FPS: " + currentFPS);
    }
    public void renderEngine(){
        if (dbImage == null){
            dbImage = createImage((int)getWidth(), (int)getHeight());
            if (dbImage == null){
                System.out.println("Graphical Context Error : DBImage is Null");
                return;
            } else {
                dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
            }
        }

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) dbg;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        FPSTextField.render(g2d, Color.MAGENTA);
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure why this keeps happening and I have searched for help but can not find the answer. Thanks in advance for all who help :)

EDIT: Added code for the TextField object:

```
package io.shparki.PhysicsEngine;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;

public class TextField{

    private Point location;
    public Point getLocation(){ return location; }
    public double getX() { return location.getX(); }
    public double getY() { return location.getY(); }

    private String text;
    public void setText(String text) { this.text = text; }
    public String getText() { return this.text; }

    public TextField(String text, int x, int y){
        this.location = new Point(x, y);
        this.text = text;
    }
    public TextField(String text, Point location){
        this.location = location;
        this.text = text;
    }


    public void render(Graphics g){
        g.drawString(text, (int)location.getX(), (int)location.getY());
    }
    public void render(Graphics2D g2d){
        g2d.drawString(text, (int)location.getX(), (int)location.getY());
    }

    public void render(Graphics g, Color color){
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawString(text, (int)location.getX(), (int)location.getY());
    }
    public void render(Graphics2D g2d, Color color){
        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.drawString(text, (int)location.getX(), (int)location.getY());
    }

    public void render(Graphics g, Color color, Font font){
        g.setColor(color);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(text, (int)location.getX(), (int)location.getY());
    }
    public void render(Graphics2D g2d, Color color, Font font){
        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.setFont(font);
        g2d.drawString(text, (int)location.getX(), (int)location.getY());
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understood your question correctly you are asking why there is a padding between the jpanel and the jframe container? It is a default border, you can change it.

Comment: I believe so. I wish I could ask the question the better but I don't quite understand whats going on myself. In the JFrame, I would like the panel to originate in the upper left corner of the window of the JFrame, but instead it originates in the upper left corner of the JFrame itself (As in past the border). I believe, due to that, I get white padding on the right and bottom of the panel, even though it should all be black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred size of the `JPanel` `EnginePanel` restricts the panel from being resized the `JFrame` is rendered non-resizable. Invoke `JFrame#pack` after calling `setResizable(false)`. Also move `setLocationRelativeTo` after pack so that the frame appears centered.

```
pack();
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! So that helped the position of the JPanel to where I want it, but how come if I were to change:

FPSTextField = new TextField("Currnet FPS: " + currentFPS, 25, 25);

to:

FPSTextField = new TextField("Currnet FPS: " + currentFPS, 0, 0);

the TextField doesn't show?

Comment: The layout manager uses `0,0` as the very top-left of the `JFrame`. You have to allow for the size of the window decorations

Comment: is there anyway to set 0,0 as the top left corner of the window rather than the JFrame, or how would you find the size of the decorations?

Comment: Not by custom painting the `String` but you can using a `JLabel` with suitable layout e.g. `FlowLayout.LEFT` letting the layout manager do the work. To get the size of the decorations use `JFrame#getInsets`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a GridBagLayout in the JFrame, then the JPanel will be centered if it is the only thing you add to the JFrame. It will even stay in the center if you resize the window.

Also, the reason the coordinates seem off to you is that you are viewing it as an (x, y) coordinate while it is actually a (row, col) coordinate like in a 2D Array.